# A sentence that uses the past tense of two verbs one after another

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, grammaticality, past-tense

Is the following sentence grammatical? The phrase "appeared formulated" sounds strange to me, as it involves the past tense two times.

> Later, the statement appeared formulated with other notions.

Probably, is the following reformulation a better way to say it?

> Later, the statement appeared in terms of other notions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Formulated" can be better understood as a participle, and not past tense. In regular (weak) verbs the participle and past tense have the same form, so this can be confusing, but consider:

> John appeared driven to achieve his goals.

You can see in this sentence that the particple "driven" is used and not the past tense "drove".

The meaning is the same as a passive phrase:

> the statement appeared to be formulated with other notions

The verb "appeared" is a linking verb, and the sentence can be completed with adjectives, prepostional phrases, infinitives or participles:

> He appeared happy.

> He appeared in a red dress.

> He appeared driven.

etc

Comment: Ok, thank you. What about "The statement appeared in the formulation [...]" - is this non-sense?

Comment: Actually I don't really know what "formulated with other notions" really means. Perhaps I'd understand if I knew the context (like what the statement is, what notions were used)  So I can't really say if "in a formulation..." is an acceptable alternative.